# How to retrieve model properties in helper methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a html helper method with the following signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelperMethod<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

I know I can get the value of the property being passed as an expression using the following:

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
object modelValue = metadata.Model;
```

In the same model, I have another property for which I want to retrieve the value in this helper method. How would I retrieve the value of this other property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using reflection.

```
var property = typeof (TModel).GetProperty("yourProperty", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var value = property.GetValue(helper.ViewData.Model, null);
```

constant "yourProperty" could of course be a parameter of your helper method.

There's maybe a nicer way, but this one should work.

Comment: This works for a property within the same class as the model, but what if my property is in the base class for the model? Any way how I can get the property value that is in the base?

Comment: @TK1 with correct bindingFlags (as edited), you'll get them also.